# Flutter snackbar dismiss on SnackBarAction onPressed

Tags: dart, flutter, snackbar

I want to dismiss `SnackBar` on `SnackBarAction`'s `onPressed` method. I tried with `Navigator.of(context).pop();` but `SnackBar` is not dismissing my screen get black instead.

Here is code:

```
 void showInSnackBar(String value) {
homeScaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(value),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    label: 'Dissmiss',
    textColor: Colors.yellow,
    onPressed: () {
    //  Navigator.of(context).pop();
    },
  ),));
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try using `hideCurrentSnackBar` method

```
onPressed: () {
    homeScaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
},
```

**Update**

Use ScaffoldMessenger instead, heee you have the guide:

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger

More info here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldMessengerState/hideCurrentSnackBar.html

Comment: The link has died.

Answer (score 96):

You can also use,

```
Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
```

Be careful when you use **context**, use the correct context.

**NOTE**

In the new Flutter Version, this method is deprecated.
Therefore use

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
```

Comment: You can also use Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar() to dismiss the SnackBar immediately without the exit animation.

Comment: Better use keys instead of context,

Answer (score 17):

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
```

Comment: this is the latest answer for anyone new here --> since Flutter 2.0 the scaffold.snackbar is deprecated and the scaffold messenger is the new way to go

Answer (score 8):

To clear the previous snackbars & show only the new one, use **removeCurrentSnackBar** method rather than **hideCurrentSnackBar** as it does not clear the stack. So the code will be

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) 
  ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
  ..showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to replace snackbar that show only one time,

```
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("Hello, world"));
```

And also,

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
```

And also,

```
onPressed: () {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.removeCurrentSnackBar();
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
     }
```

Comment: I liked this solution because it immediately removes snack bar. (I think) In my case I am not left with a queue of snack bar animations playing if a series of "showSnackBar()" calls are made.

Answer (score 4):

**Define your `SnackBar`:**

```dart
var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Hello World'));
```

**To show it:**

```dart
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

**To hide it:**

```dart
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
```

**To hide the last one and show a new one:**

```dart
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) 
  ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
  ..showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Answer (score 2):

All these answers will not work because you cannot reference the ScarfoldMessenger from a Snackbar.
You'll have to save a reference to the snackbar and call it's "close" method. Like so
 `void Function () close; var snackbar = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showsnackbar(Snackbar (content:Text(), action: SnackbarAction(onPressed:()=>close())) close = ()=> snackbar.close();`

Answer (score 1):

Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
Above method is used previously but,

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
This is now recommended.

Answer (score 1):

**You can also show and dismiss a snackbar like this without any key**

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(
    content: Text('Hello from snackbar!'),
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: 'Dissmiss',
      textColor: Colors.yellow,
      onPressed: () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As today using Flutter v3 there seems to be even a simpler solution to dismiss the Snackbar, which is shown on [Flutter official cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars#interactive-example), not sure if it works the same on previous versions.

It's as simple as passing an empty function to `onPressed`

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    label: 'Close',
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IconButton(
        // 1
        icon: Icon(_isFavorited ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border),
        iconSize: 30,
        // 2
        color: Colors.red[400],
        onPressed: () {
          // 3
          setState(() {
            _isFavorited = !_isFavorited;
            if (_isFavorited) {
              final snackBar = SnackBar(
                content: const Text('Added to favorite'),
                action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'Ok',
                    onPressed: () {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                    }),
              );
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            } else {
              final snackBar = SnackBar(
                content: const Text('removed from Favorite'),
                action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'Ok',
                    onPressed: () {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                    }),
              );
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            }
          });
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// dismiss with animation
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();

// dismiss without animation
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();

// remove all snackbars currently in queue, dismiss current snackbar with animation
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
```

Answer (score 0):

`hideCurrentSnackBar()` hides current snackBar, shows the next, and then shows the hidden snack bars in the end.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
```

`removeCurrentSnackBar()` removes current snackBar and shows the next, but it does not show the removed snack bars.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
```

Here are the docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger